# Animating UIImageView from an array of images - Swift

Tags: arrays, variables, animation, uiimageview, sequence

I'm trying to make a *ImageView* animate from a *PNG-Sequence*. However, in the line "`imageList = UIImage(named: imageName)`" I get an error which states the following: Missing argument for parameter 'inBundle' in call.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
var imageList = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    startAnimation()


    for i in 0...120
    {

        let imageName = "\(i)"
        imageList = UIImage(named: imageName)

    } 


}


@IBAction func generate(sender: AnyObject) {

     tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func startAnimation() -> Void
{
    myImageView.animationImages = imageList
    myImageView.startAnimating()
}
}
```

Been Googling to fix this for hours, but can't seem to find anything that works. It is the same code as in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSny6un3VUw